# ASP.NET ChangePassword userId = null

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, change-password

So, I'm trying to change user password using default ASP.NET methond, but just don't work, somehow I'm not able to get the current user data. I tried different approaches to get userId and still nothing. And I didn't change a thing except for the [AllowAnonymous], because there was a error saying permission denied when I tried to call the method.

[image]

```
// POST api/Account/ChangePassword
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ChangePassword")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword,
            model.NewPassword);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the answer... I forgot to put this on the request:

```
authorization: bearer my_token
```

Answer (score 0):

GetUserId() is an extension method on IIdentity and it is in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions. Make sure you have added the namespace with using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;.

or otherwise you can use

```
string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
```

if you using EF then User ApplicationUser code

Comment: the is no Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions, just Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;

Comment: And I can't use User.Identity.GetUserId(); because the result it's null. It's like I made the login and the parameters wasn't set.

Comment: Which authentication type you are using

Comment: local cookie-based authentication